# I've added a view to a region. Now I want to remove the view from the region from an event of the view

Tags: wpf, prism

I've added a region from the code behind file of Shell.xaml :-

```
private IRegionManager _regionManager;

private void mnuReg_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _regionManager = new RegionManager();
   _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion
      ("MainRegion", typeof(RegisterModule.Views.RegisterView));
 }///
```

Now I want to remove the view "RegisterView" from the click event of "RegisterView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IRegionManager _regionManager = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRegionManager>();

private void mnuReg_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   IRegion _mainRegion = _regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"]; 
   RegisterView _viewRegister = new RegisterView();
   _mainRegion.Add(_viewRegister);
}

private void mnuCloseAll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   foreach (object view in _regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"].Views)
   {
       _regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"].Remove(view);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only use RegisterViewWithRegion for view discovery scenarios, in which you want to automatically inject views.  You do not use this in response to a button click.  Instead you should be using Region.Add, or RequestNavigate.

Comment: You've given me right direction, which helped me to solve the problem. Thank u very much.